# How to pass enum value in soap envelope

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, enums

I try to sent soap request to server. I have this soap form where **urn:fetchType** is enum value of type FetchType:

```
public enum FetchType
{
    AllDetails = 0,
    OnlyRoot = 1
}

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="***">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetEventList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:sessionId></urn:sessionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:filterXml></urn:filterXml>
         <urn:fetchType></urn:fetchType>
         <urn:subscribe></urn:subscribe>
      </urn:GetEventList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I try to send 1 or 2 I get error response: **Instance validation error: '1' is not a valid value for FetchType.**

Also I tried to pass something like this FetchType.AllDetails and get response: **Instance validation error: 'FetchType.AllDetails1' is not a valid value for FetchType.**

and etc...different solutions.

This is a signature of method that should receive request:

`public byte[] GetEventList(string sessionId, [XmlElement(DataType = base64Binary")] byte[] filterXml, FetchType fetchType, bool subscribe)
{ ... some code ...; }`

Could you say me what way I can use to pass enum value?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Way too late for you but who knows, maybe one day someone will need the answer to this question.

Simply send the string value (eg:`AllDetails`)

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="***">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetEventList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:sessionId></urn:sessionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:filterXml></urn:filterXml>
         <urn:fetchType>AllDetails</urn:fetchType>
         <urn:subscribe></urn:subscribe>
      </urn:GetEventList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```